# How do I generate a core dump to a file on a running process using gcore <PID> in macOS Catalina? Getting error "gcore: insufficient privilege"

Tags: pid, privileges, coredump, macos-catalina, gcore

Currently I have a program that runs and sleeps for 60 seconds. I get the PID of the program and I run "sudo gcore (PID of process)". But I am getting the message "gcore: insufficient privilege" in the terminal. I am not sure why this is happening and how to resolve this..

when I run "info gcore" I see that the format is:

`gcore [-s] [-v] [-b size] [-o path | -c pathformat] pid`

Using the above format, can any one also give an example of a gcore command that generates a core dump on a running process using the process id and saves that core dump to a specific file path?

Note: I also installed the home-brew version of gcore as told in another stack overflow post but that didn't help